# How to retrieve array of value by name using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a HTML as below.
Please tell me how can I retrieve the value 'task' array in jQuery.

```
<div class="column1">
<input class="task_name" type="text" placeholder="Enter task name.." value="" name="task[0][name]">
</div>
<div class="column2">
<select class="task_ppl_required" name="task[0][number]">
    <option selected="selected">1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<input class="task_id" type="hidden" value="0" name="task[0][guid]">
</div>
<div class="column1">
<input class="task_name" type="text" placeholder="Enter task name.." value="" name="task[2][name]">
</div>
<div class="column2">
<select class="volunteer_task_ppl_required" name="task[2][number]" value="1">
<option selected="selected">1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
<input class="task_id" type="hidden" value="0" name="task[2][guid]">
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by task array?

Comment: You mean $(".task_name")

Comment: how is anyone to guess what i"task array" is when virtually all elements of form have "task" in them.

Comment: Can you show, clearly, what you expect us to find?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. As you see in the HTML there are input elements with name like task[0][name], task[0][number], task[0][guid], task[2][name],task[2][number],task[2][guid].The name of elements is same i.e.,task.I want to retrieve all input/select elements value as task

Comment: so do Bergi's demos do what you want? If not...you need to be concise about what format you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getValues(form) {
    var vals = {};
    form.find("[name]").each(function() {
        var names = this.name.split(/[[\]]+/);
        if (names[names.length-1] == "") names.pop();
        var obj = vals;
        for (var i=0; i<names.length-1; i++) {
            if (! (names[i] in obj))
                obj[names[i]] = {};
            obj = obj[names[i]];
        }
        obj[names[i]] = this.value;
    });
    return vals;
}
```

Instead of `.find("[name]")` you also could just use [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), which might be more exact and allow more inputs. Now, you can

```
> getValues($myForm).task[0]
{number: "1", guid: "0"}
```

([Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ5FB/), [more sophisticated](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ5FB/1/) using Array.reduce)

Answer (score 1):

The array aproximation works well in PHP, where you receive the form values on the $_POST variable and if the syntax match (as yours in the example) he would construct an array with the elements.

You could use jQuery [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). From the site:

> The .serializeArray() method creates a JavaScript array of objects, ready to be encoded as a JSON string. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form elements.

Comment: It's more than only `serializeArray`, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ5FB/1/) from my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the values of form in order to send to server you can simply use jQuery `serialize()` method

```
var formVals= $('##myForm').serialize();
```

This gets sent to server using jQuery AJAX in folloing manner:

```
$.post( url, formVals, function(){/* success code*/});
```

Reference:  http://api.jquery.com/serialize/